# Adding Text before a Date in a Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

How can I achieve "Current Date: <Today's Date>" in a cell in Google Sheets? The "Today's Date" part must update dynamically every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `trim()`, `to_text()` or `text()` to turn the dateserial value returned by `today()` to a readable date, like this:

`="Current Date: " & trim(today())`